# GCP Vertex AI Managed Notebook cannot use custom container

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

In GCP Vertex AI, I created a Managed Notebook by specifying one of our custom containers which work perfectly with User-Managed Notebook kernels.
The Managed Notebook starts, and Jupyter Lab seems to work without any signs of error.

Unfortunately, if I look at the available kernels in Jupyter Lab, only the default kernels are listed but not my custom kernel.

An activity log entry on the right shows a spinning wheel "Loading kernel from [custom container]" which never disappears.
Taking a look at the terminal,

*docker image ls*

does not show the custom container either; obviously, it was not even pulled to the Managed Notebook.

If I perform

*docker pull [custom container]*

in the terminal, to test connectivity to the Artifact Registry then it pulls the container correctly as expected.
However, the custom kernel is still not visible in Jupyter Lab (even after a notebook restart).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue today, and after some experimentation, I found that I haven't fulfilled all the requirements in [Vertex AI docs](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/custom-container).
One in particular - The Docker container image must support sleep infinity.

And my Dockerfile contained

```
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT [ "jupyter", "lab", "--allow-root", "--ip", "0.0.0.0", "--config", "/opt/jupyter/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py" ]
```

To enable sleep infinity I replaced `ENTRYPOINT` with

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep infinity"]
```

then the kernelspec was imported, but the notebook wasn't able to connect.

So I removed the `ENTRYPOINT` entirely and then the kernelspec was imported and the notebook was able to connect successfully.

Hope that helps.