# Can't create Vertex AI (GCP) notebook with custom container

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to create a Vertex AI notebook using a Custom Container to train my torch model on GCP. I wasn't able to correctly generate a notebook using this custom container and I can't understand why. I tried to look at the documentation but wasn't able to identify any pages that would help me.

Here's what I'm doing currently:

1. My `app` has this general structure:

```
├───data
│   └───dataset
│       ├───__init__.py
│       └───GraphDataset.py
├───model
│   ├───__init__.py
│   └───autoencoder.py
├───util
│   ├───__init__.py
│   └───utils.py
├───__init__.py
└───main.py
```

2. My Dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM python:3.8

# Install system dependencies required for project
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential gcc
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Python requirements file into the container
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install torch==2.0.1
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt \
    && pip install jupyterlab \
    && pip install google-cloud-storage

# Copy the rest of the application's code into the container
COPY . /app

# Expose the JupyterLab port
EXPOSE 8080

# Start JupyterLab
CMD ["jupyter", "lab", "--port=8080", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--no-browser", "--ServerApp.token=''", "--ServerApp.password=''", "--allow-root"]
```

3. I was able to succesfully build my docker container using

```
docker build -t gcr.io/[PROECT-ID]/code:v2 .
docker push gcr.io/[PROECT-ID]/code:v2
```

4. I'm able to pull an image of this container and generate a local Jupyter Lab instance with the intended structure.
5. I can select this container from GCR when creating a `USER-MANAGED NOTEBOOK` on Vertex AI
6. The problem is: when I open the generated Vertex AI notebook the files I find are the default ones (`src`, `tutorial`, etc). The files I expected to see are nowhere to be found.
7. Furthermore, the kernel can't connect (it either stays "Connecting..." forever or just "Disconnected").

What I've tried:

1. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75172081/12684122) I've tried to create a container with
   a. the sleep infinity command (`ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep infinity"]`); and

   b. with no ENTRYPOINT at all

   both failed (a. and for b. I couldn't open the Vertex AI's notebook (ERR502)).
2. Create a docker using a gcr image as base (`FROM gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cpu.py37`), but build failed.

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate any guidance!